# How to write encrypted data to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

As Apache Hadoop 2.6 has recently introduced HDFS-6134 (Transparent Data at Rest Encryption), I would like to know whether it is possible to directly write into an Encryption Zone using a Java Hadoop application? The documentation only explains the command `hdfs crypto createZone keyName myKey path /encryptionZone` to copy a file to an Encrypted Zone but I'd like to know how I can use the api to write into an Encrypted Zone?

Answer (score 3):

You surely cannot write encrypted data directly to an already created encrypted zone. This is simply not possible as the encryption/decryption is not done at the application level. Hadoop DFS Client would "transparently" encrypt/decrypt the data upon each write/read.

You can read the actual design document of this transparent encryption for more details.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12660368/HDFSDataatRestEncryption.pdf